# The Office Open XML file Can not be open because there are problems with contents How To Fix

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, ms-office

I am Using This Function To Write the File.When Open My file MS Office Showing Pop-UP The Office Open XML file Can not be open because there are problems with contents How To Fix

```
    zszFilePath = Path.Combine(xszAttachmentPath, xszInternalFileName);
                    FileStream zfsSourceFile = new FileStream(zszFilePath, FileMode.Open);
    znFileSize = (int)zfsSourceFile.Length;
    byte[] zbGetContent = new byte[znFileSize];
    zfsSourceFile.Read(zbGetContent, 0, znFileSize);
    zfsSourceFile.Close();
    zObjContext.Response.BinaryWrite(zbGetContent);
```

Comment: If there are problems with the contents then you should probably fix the contents?  The error is literally in plain readable English...  Why are you asking?

Comment: No Problem With Contents

Answer (score 0):

Validate the document you created in the Open XML format with the OpenXMLValidator. With that you can also test to see what is wrong with the file.

For more information read the blogpost

[Validate Open XML Documents using the Open XML SDK 2.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericwhite/2010/03/04/validate-open-xml-documents-using-the-open-xml-sdk-2-0/)

or

[Finding Open XML Errors with Open XML SDK Validation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_jones/archive/2009/09/24/finding-open-xml-errors-with-open-xml-sdk-validation.aspx)

Hope it helps. If not please provide either the file you try to open or be more descriptive to what is in there. The current information is too limited to answer properly.